# Integration in measure theory, modes of convergence

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I have this problem on the integration topic in measure theory, I can't find the way to achieve the equality with the funcion evaluated in zero. I find it somehow related with the Dirac measure, but I can still not completely link it, the exercise is
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous and $g_n:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{\lVert x \rVert\leq 1}g_nd\lambda=1$ and $g_n\rightarrow0$ uniformly at $0<c\leq \lVert x \rVert\leq 1$ for every $c>0$. Show that $\\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\lVert x \rVert\leq 1}fg_nd\lambda=f(0)$

Comment: Are you sure, this is the statement, you want to show? If I take $g_n(x)=1/n$ and $f(x)=1$ as constant functions, I would obtain $\int_{|| x||\leq 1}fg_nd\lambda=(1/n)\lambda(\lbrace x:|| x|| \leq 1\rbrace)=\pi/n\to 0$ but $f(0)=1$. But maybe, I misunderstood your question. Or is your goal to find $g_n$ with the property, you described?

Comment: @GrafZahl - $\int_{\|x\|\le 1} \frac 1n d\lambda \ne 1$ so that doesn't fit the given conditions on $g_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Since $f$ is continuous on a compact set, $|f(x)| < M$ for some $M$, and all $\|x\| \le 1$.

if $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta$ such that if $\|x\|< \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(0)| < \epsilon/2$, and there is an $n$ such that $|g_n(x)| < \epsilon/4M\pi$ when $\|x\| \ge \delta$.